# How to set global setting for embedded movies in Latex?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, movie15, multimedia

I create slides using latex beamer which as about 180 slides in total with over 40 videos.

I inserted the videos using this command:

```
\begin{frame}
 \framesubtitle{Demo}
    \begin{figure}
      \newcommand{\iheight}{\textheight}
      \newcommand{\iwidth}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \movie[label=show1,width=\iwidth, poster,
      autostart, loop] {
        \includegraphics[width=\iwidth, trim={0 0 0 0},
        clip]{../videos/cover/demo32}
      } {../videos/demo32.mpg}
    \end{figure}
  }
\end{frame}
```

In all the videos I embedded, I used the above style. Playing videos during presentation is really difficult as presentation software [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) unexpectedly crashes. It also takes ages for it to load.

I figured out that if I use `evince` and use external media player like VLC solves the problem. To do that I have to update the snippet above as follows by adding `externalviewer` to the properties.

```
\begin{frame}
 \framesubtitle{Demo}
    \begin{figure}
      \newcommand{\iheight}{\textheight}
      \newcommand{\iwidth}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \movie[label=show1,width=\iwidth, poster,
      autostart, loop, externalviewer] {
        \includegraphics[width=\iwidth, trim={0 0 0 0},
        clip]{../videos/cover/demo32}
      } {../videos/demo32.mpg}
    \end{figure}
  }
\end{frame}
```

For your reference, the you can find documentation for [Movie15](ftp://ftp.u-aizu.ac.jp/pub/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/movie15.pdf) CTAN package.

My question is instead of manually added `exteralviewer`, is there a way I can just set the **externalviewer** and it has a global effect on all the `\movie[]{}` macros.

For example:
To set all the frame-title to bold we do

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
```

Can similar be done for the movie?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably redefine the `\movie` command to set the external viewer to true as default:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\movie[3][]{%
  \leavevmode%
  % Sanity check
  \IfFileExists{\@currdir #3}{}{%
    \PackageWarning{multimedia}{The movie file ``#3'' could not be
      found in the current directory, where it must reside for
      viewing.}%
  }%
  {%
    % Calculate size of the poster
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{#2}%
    \@tempdima=\wd\@tempboxa%
    \@tempdimb=\ht\@tempboxa%
    \@tempdimc=\dp\@tempboxa%
    \global\advance\mm@movie by1\relax%
    \edef\mm@label{mmdefaultlabel\the\mm@movie}%
    \def\mm@playmode{}%
    \def\mm@duration{}%
    \def\mm@start{}%
    \def\mm@poster{}%
    \def\mm@controls{}%
    \mm@autostartfalse%
    \mm@externaltrue% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% <- change made here
    \def\mm@bw{0}%
    \setkeys{multimedia}{#1}%
    \wd\@tempboxa=\@tempdima%
    \ht\@tempboxa=\@tempdimb%
    \dp\@tempboxa=\@tempdimc%
    \ifmm@external%
      \href{run:#3}{\box\@tempboxa}%
    \else%
      \mm@psorpdf{%
        \pdfmark[{\box\@tempboxa}]{%
          pdfmark=/ANN,%
          Subtype=/Movie,%
          Movie=<< /F (#3) \mm@poster\space >>,%
          Annotations=<< \mm@start\space \mm@duration\space \mm@playmode\space \mm@controls\space>>,%
          T=(\mm@label),
          Border={0 0 \mm@bw}}%
       }{%
        \pdfannot width \@tempdima height \@tempdimb depth \@tempdimc
        {
          /Subtype /Movie
          /T (\mm@label)
          /Border [0 0 \mm@bw]
          /Movie << /F (#3) \mm@poster\space >>
          /A << \mm@start\space \mm@duration\space \mm@playmode\space \mm@controls\space >>
        }%
      }%
      \mm@psorpdf{}{\box\@tempboxa}%
      \ifmm@autostart%
      \mm@psorpdf%
      {%
        \pdfmark{pdfmark=/PUT,%
           Raw={{ThisPage} << /AA << /O << /S /Movie
         /T (\mm@label) /Operation /Play >> >> >>}%
      }}%
      {%
        \immediate\pdfobj {<< /S /Movie /T (\mm@label) /Operation /Play >>}%
        \pdfannot width 0pt height 0pt depth 0pt {%
          /Subtype/Widget
          /FT/Btn/Ff 65537
          /T (wid@\mm@label)
          /AA <</PO \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>>% attention: /O --> /PO for Widget annots
        }%  
      }%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

or use `xpatch` for a shorter code.

*(untested, as the question does not include a compilable example)*